# Cisco ACL Not Applying

Tags: cisco, ios

This is probably something extreamly simple but I am executing the following code to block usage of port 80 on ip 192.168.1.50 and it does not seem to be working. The interface is right and I am using a Cisco Router 2820. Here is the code I used:

```
(config) access-list 101 deny tcp any host 192.168.1.50 eq 80
(config) access-list 101 permit ip any any
(config-if) ip access-group 101 in
(config-if) ip access-group 101 out
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the interface you're applying that to a vlan or a physical port?  And is it a switched port, or routed?  And where is that 192.168.1.50 device relative to the interface's subnet?

Comment: This is an actual physical port and not a vlan. It is a routed port as well. The device goes to a switch 3500XL switch first then to the 2820 router which has the ACL on it.

Comment: Where is 192.168.1.50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess that 192.168.1.50 is a local device, and that you're trying to prevent it from getting out to the internet on port 80?

If that's the case, then your ACL's a bit backwards; try this:

```
access-list 101 deny tcp host 192.168.1.50 gt 1023 any eq 80
```

And the `in` is the only one you'll need:

```
ip access-group 101 in
```

Comment: what does the gt 1023 do exactly?

Comment: Source ports greater than 1023.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).  If you're trying to block connections to port 80 on all devices, when the connection is sourced from 192.168.1.50, then this is what you want.

Comment: This was really great and helped me out a lot, thank you very much for your post.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you can only apply it IN or OUT, not both at the same time ;).

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to apply it `in` and `out`, but it'll work.

Comment: You can certainly apply a single ACL both in- and out-bound. I have done it multiple times. Admittedly prima=rily for "tracking" ACLs (with specific "ip permit" statements for what I am interested in, finishing with a blanket "ip permit any any")

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest two ACLs?

Deny traffic coming INTO the router from anywhere destined for 192.168.1.50 on port 80:

```
(config) access-list 101 deny tcp any host 192.168.1.50 eq 80
(config-if) ip access-group 101 in
```

Allow any traffic out of the router from anywhere to anywhere:

```
(config) access-list 102 permit ip any any
(config-if) ip access-group 102 out
```